# Saving new asset as first index in assets field?

Tags: frontend-form, assets-field

I have a front-end Entry form that has a file input for adding a new Asset to the Entry. It works fine except that I have the special requirement of wanting to add the new asset as the first index in the list of assets. I've tried ordering the inputs on the form accordingly, but as far as I can tell it doesn't matter and will always add the existing assets first and the new asset last.

Is there a way to place it at the front even though it's a new asset?

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  {{ csrfInput() }}
  {{ actionInput('entries/save-entry') }}
  {{ hiddenInput('sectionId', 3) }}

  <input type="file" name="fields[photos][]">

  {% if myExistingEntry %}

    {{ hiddenInput('entryId', myExistingEntry.id) }}

    {% for photo in myExistingEntry.photos.all() %}
      <input type="hidden" name="fields[photos][]" value="{{ photo.id }}" />
    {% endfor %}

  {% endif %}

  <button>Save</button>

</form>
```